# Python 3 Using Sockets over the Internet

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, client, server

I have been trying to set up sockets that will work over the internet. I have search high and low through stack overflow and cannot seem to find the answer I need.

When I run server.py I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 16, in <module>
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Note that the following seems to work over local wifi.

The server code:

```
# server.py 
import socket                                      

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 


#get ip address
print("You are the server.")
print("What is your ip? If you do not know, look up <my ip> on google.")
host = input(">")                         

port = 0                                          

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)   
clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()                                          

def messenger():
    # establish a connection    
    tm = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    tm = tm.decode('ascii')

    if tm == "9+10":
        message = "21"
    elif tm == "sweg":
        message = "swegedy swooty feel the booty"
    else:
        message = "feggeet"
    clientsocket.send(message.encode('ascii'))
    messenger()
messenger()
```

The client side code:

```
# client.py  
import socket

#get ip address
print("You are the client.")
print("What is your servers ip?")
host = input(">")  

# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

port = 0
s.connect((host, port))

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
def messenger():
    message = input("command:")
    s.send(message.encode("ascii"))
    tm = s.recv(1024)                                     
    print(tm.decode('ascii'))
    messenger()
messenger()
```

From what I have learned, this should work as long as I insert a public IP address. However, I just get that error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: note that your `messenger` function will eventually overflow the stack because you're calling it from itself over and over.  Instead, just put the read/write logic into a loop and exit the loop (and the messenger function) upon receipt of some specific string.

Comment: Alright, I'll fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server can only bind to a host address upon which it is located.  IIRC, you should bind to 0.0.0.0, this binds to all addresses on the current machine.  You can then connect the client locally (same machine 127.0.0.1, local machine - you'll need to know the internal IP address of the machine).

Correction, the common method is `serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80))`

If you want to access it from the internet the first thing you'll need to know is the internet address of you machine. Since it's unlikely that you're connected directly to the internet, this will like be the IP address of your router.

The next step will be to allow port forwarding through the router to your machine - again, a huge treatise can be written about this.

Comment: I know the internet address, how do I go about port forwarding?

Comment: That's a huge subject, specific to your router - start with the documentation and go on to the mfr web site.  IOW, that's sysadmin, not programming.

Comment: Is this the only way to make a python program that will work over the internet? There must be an easier way...

Comment: python has nothing to do with it - if the 'internet' can't get to your computer then you have nothing.   Any program can go out to the internet but getting in to your server is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my python code as well now it's fixed!

what you have to do is firstly you need to bind the server to the localhost, not the public ip address: `SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`

Secondly, you need to set the client side of the addresses to the public ip of the server, not the local ip: `SERVER = '<server side public ip address goes here>'`

If that doesn't work for you don't worry you need to enable port forwarding in your router you can probably find how to on the internet!

then most people just get bored of this cause it won't work but it will after the last step!

If you are using windows this is much easier since I use windows as my OP Im going to show you how to do this with screenshots:
Firstly you need to go to the windows firewall settings and under there click on advanced settings
[image: windows firewall settings]

after that, this should pop up!
[image]

then click the inbound Rules and in the top right click New Rule!

in there you can click on port and click next and select the port that you are using in your python client or server python file:

[image]

after that click allow this connection and click next and next until finish and then do for the server and make sure to do it for all the client machines as well!!:

after that, you need to set it again but this time it should be for UDP:
if you did both then give it a try.

Comment: and the second step needs to be in the client side k?